# Using text search and sorting in find_one_and_update with PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have created some text indexes and want to use text search to find and update a specific document (while also sorting). In [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#sorting) they show you how you can find a specific document, while sorting by "textScore", and so I've converted this to Python like so:

```
db.stores.find(
    {"$text": {"$search": "java coffee shop"}},
    {"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}
).sort([("score", {"$meta": "textScore"})])
```

and this works fine. However, I also want to create a function that can find 1 specific store, and update this using $set. I've tried using the following piece of code to do this:

```
db.stores.find_one_and_update(
    {"$text": {"$search": search_string}},
    {"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}},
    {"$set": store_attributes},
    sort=[("score", {"$meta": "textScore"})]
)
```

Looking at the 4th example given [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) I thought this would work, but unfortunately it gives the error

```
ValueError: update only works with $ operators
```

Of course I can use a roundabout way, like using `find()` with a `limit(1)` and then use that to update the document in the collection, but I'd rather try to do it like this. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and in my mind this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the second parameter to `find_one_and_update` is the update operation to perform, not the projection. So the second parameter should be your `$set` object, not your `score` projection.

However, it doesn't matter because it appears that the `sort` can only be done on actual fields of the documents, not a `$meta` field like `score`.

So I think using the `find().limit(1)` approach you mention is the way to go here.

That said, using a `$text` query to update a document does feel a bit non-deterministic, which may be why this isn't directly supported.